# extjs-store-load

Tags: extjs

I have simple grid with a store. When I add a record to a store it reflects on the grid. But on few occasions when toggle between browser tabs.

The `store` load event seem to fire from then on when I add a record to the store its getting added but it don't seem to reflect on the grid

How do I stop the extjs store load event from firing on its own?

Comment: the event does not fire on its own. Something causes it to fire. What are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about adding the following config option to your store?

```
autoLoad: false
```